# Merging tibbles with left_join - increase of cases?

Tags: r, join, merge, left-join, tibble

I have a very basic question, but I dont really know how this can happen:

I have two tibbles/data.frames called "data1" and "data2". Now, I would like to keep "data1" and add all values in "data2" where the columns "variable1" and "variable2" (which appear in both tibbles) are identical. Therefore I do a left_join:

```
library(dplyr)
newData <- left_join(data1, data2, by=c("variable1", "variable"))
```

However, If I check the number of rows, nrow(data1) is smaller than nrow(newData). How can this be or why does this happen? Why does the number of cases increase?

Comment: Please show us input datasets and this *loss of cases*. As of now, we'll take your word for it.

Comment: Excuse me, it's not a LOSS. Its an INCREASE: from 17116 to 17139 cases. Unfortunately, I cannot show the original data as it is secret.

Comment: Consider editing even the title as that is a very important overlook. And see this [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Do you have variables that are `NA` in `variable1` and `variable2`?

Comment: Just checked it... there is only one NA in data2$variable2.

Answer (score 1):

it just means that data2 has multiple values for some entries in data1.